# Reading and writing csv files

Tags: c++, csv, fstream

The function of this program is that. when the user runs this they are asked for 3 inputs. date (DDMMYY) bodypart trained (eg. chest) and Time (eg. 100) Depending on the user input for a condition. The user can store new data. or view stored data.

When the user stores data, the data goes to the file fine. When they view this data it shows them. This is the correct intended functionality.

The problem occurs when they restart the program and enter another set of information. This set of info overwrites the last set. so only the latest entry of data is shown.

**1. How do i make it so when the program is restarted and new data is inputted the data appends to the file instead of overwriting it?
2. My other question is how can i repeat the function in the same run of the program?
once i press ctrl z to end the inputs the file just stops
and says press any key to continue...**

```
workoutlogger.cpp

#include "workoutlogger.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "mainclient.h"

using namespace std;


workoutlogger::workoutlogger()
{
    int choices;
    cout << " (1) Do you want to log a new workout\n (2) Track previous workouts?\n Enter the number of your choice\n";
    cin >> choices;

    switch (choices) {
    case 1:
        log();
        break;

    case 2:
        viewinfo();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "invalid option..";
        workoutlogger();
    }


}


workoutlogger::~workoutlogger()
{
}

int workoutlogger::log()
{
    ofstream theFile("workinfo.txt");

    cout << "enter date (DDMMYY), bodypart trained (eg. Chest), time trained (mins)" << endl;
    cout << "press ctrl + z to quit\n";

    int date;
    string bodypart;
    int minutes;

    while (cin >> date >> bodypart >> minutes) 
    {

        theFile << date << ' ' << bodypart << ' ' << minutes << endl;
    }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
}

int workoutlogger::viewinfo() {

        ifstream theFile("workinfo.txt");

        int date;
        string bodypart;
        int minutes;

        while (theFile >> date >> bodypart >> minutes) { //stores infomation in these variables
                                                         //file pointer starts at first piece of info, then onto next info to store in variables
            cout << date << ", " << bodypart << ", " << minutes << endl;

        }
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

workoutlogger.h

```
#pragma once
class workoutlogger
{
public:
    workoutlogger();
    ~workoutlogger();
    int viewinfo();
    int log();
};
```

Comment: Your file is delimited by spaces, not commas, and you should check the documentation for fstream to understand how to append to a file.  Without seeing your `main` function, or however you call these others functions it's going to be difficult to do anything but guess at your second question. Short answer, call the function again.

Comment: Ideological point: This class has no state (no data members). Ask yourself, "Why is it a class?"

Answer (score 0):

Opening a file for appending is pretty simple, just open it like before, put pass the append flag like this

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open ("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

To exit, why don't you just look for an input of "exit" and assume that is an exit condition and not valid input.

Something like:

```
while (cin >> date >> bodypart >> minutes) 
{
    if(date == "exit") {
        return 0;
    }
    theFile << date << ' ' << bodypart << ' ' << minutes << endl;
}
```